# Python 3.5 Scipy Optimize Import Error

Tags: python

Encountered the following problem when trying to use the module scipy.optimize.slsqp.

```
>>> import scipy.optimize.slsqp
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/optimize/__init__.py",      
line 233, in <module>
from ._minimize import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 26, in <module>
from ._trustregion_dogleg import _minimize_dogleg
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_dogleg.py", line 5, in <module>
import scipy.linalg
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/linalg/__init__.py", 
line 190, in <module>
from ._decomp_update import *
File "scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.pyx", line 1, in init 
scipy.linalg._decomp_update (scipy/linalg/_decomp_update.c:39096)
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: 
undefined symbol: zlacn2
```

I'm using Python3.5, Scipy 0.17.0, Numpy 1.10.1, the OS is CentOS 5.11. Could anyone shed some lights into this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SciPy math dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev
```

The above command is for Debian related OS. Please check what has to be installed for CentOS

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I installed SciPy math dependencies for Centos using sudo yum install blas-devel lapack-devel. However, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the math dependencies

> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev